# Creating a new file from existing file

Tags: c#

I have a text file that looks like this when I open it using a streamreader: (The "Remove" is just to show you what I want to do)

```
A, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
B, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2
B, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
A, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5  -- Remove
A, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
A, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5  -- Remove
B, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2  -- Remove
B, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1  -- Remove
A, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
B, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2
```

The "A"s are the parent rows and the "B"s are children rows directly below parent rows.  Some A's may not have children rows.  Basically, I want a new text file that only has the A's and their children (B's) where the second field in the A's row does not include a 2.  So my new text file (using streamwriter) would look like:

```
A, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
B, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2
B, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
A, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
A, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
B, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2
```

I can get the lines A, without "2", ...  but having a hard time getting it's children lines below it...

Help anyone?

I think I got it working, but it's not elegant:

```
List<string> str = new List<string>();

 while (!file.EndOfStream)
            {                
                var line = file.ReadLine();
                str.Add(line);
            }

        file.Close();


 using (var sw = new StreamWriter(file))
            {
                for(int i = 0; i <= str.Count-1; i++)
                {
                    var values = str[i].Split(',');
                    if (values[0] == "A" && values[1] != "2")
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(str[i]);

                        int j = i+1;

                        for (int e = j; e <= str.Count - 1; e++)
                        {
                            var values2 = str[e].Split(',');
                            if (values2[0] == "B")
                            {
                                sw.WriteLine(str[e]);
                            }else if(values2[0] == "A")
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: can you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: Your deletion criteria is not at all clear.

Comment: I added the code I have so far.. which seems kind of work.. I have to keep testing, but its not elegant.

Comment: What is the problem? The deletion criteria, or actually writing the file? What do you mean by it "kind of works"?

Comment: Basically, I "think" I got it working - meaning, I am able to get the "A" rows w/o the "2" immediately following it and the children (B) - , but I don't think its elegant and wondered if anyone had a better way?

Comment: It basically looks OK although I wouldn't read everything into a list first, it's probably just a waste of memory. Read a line, if A,2, write to file and do the inner loop, if A,!2 read the next line.

Comment: Thank you.  I always tend to just write "OK" code and know it can be refactored to be better.  I will take it out of the list first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do something like this. Note that this assumes that the file always looks like your example and does no error checking:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputFile))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputFile))
{
    bool delete = false;
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        string[] lineItems = line.Split(',');
        if (lineItems[0].Trim() == "A")
            delete = lineItems[1].Trim() == "2";
        if (!delete)
            writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!, this was definitely a lot more elegant than mine!

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know from the current `A` that you will remove it and any B's following it, you could simply retain the state in a boolean.

```
static void ProcessStream(TextReader input, TextWriter output)
{
    bool remove = false;
    string line;
    while ((line = input.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var parts = line.Split(',');
        //for A, decide to remove this and next lines
        if (parts[0] == "A")
            remove = parts[1].Contains("2");

        if (!remove)
            output.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```